# Dockerfile, how install snap, snapd: unrecognized service

Tags: docker, ubuntu, service, debian, dockerfile

well I got some problem with my Dockerfile, in fact I try to install `snapd` on Debian and Ubuntu in almost all version.

When I try to launch a command I got this error

`error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/rocketchat-server: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory`

So I tried to see if the service is enabled, and there is no service called `snapd`, even if I try to start with systemctl `systemctl start snapd`, I have an error

`Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`

so I installed `dbus`, and when I try again now I have this error

`Failed to start snapd.service: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1`

I tried to start the service with service or journalctl and it shows

`snapd: unrecognized service`

When I list all my services I have this

```
 [ - ]  apparmor

 [ - ]  bootmisc.sh

 [ - ]  checkfs.sh

 [ - ]  checkroot-bootclean.sh

 [ - ]  checkroot.sh

 [ + ]  dbus

 [ - ]  hostname.sh

 [ ? ]  hwclock.sh

 [ - ]  killprocs

 [ - ]  mountall-bootclean.sh

 [ - ]  mountall.sh

 [ - ]  mountdevsubfs.sh

 [ - ]  mountkernfs.sh

 [ - ]  mountnfs-bootclean.sh

 [ - ]  mountnfs.sh

 [ ? ]  ondemand

 [ - ]  procps

 [ - ]  rc.local

 [ - ]  sendsigs

 [ + ]  udev

 [ - ]  umountfs

 [ - ]  umountnfs.sh

[ - ]  umountroot

 [ - ]  urandom
```

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade &&\
    apt-get install -y snap snapd

RUN snap install rocketchat-server
#"error: cannot communicate with server: Post #http://localhost/v2/snaps/rocketchat-server: dial unix #/run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory"

RUN snap --version
#snap    2.40
#snapd   unavailable
#series  -

EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT Server is running .... && tail -f /dev/null
```

I know that with docker playing with service is not good but I don't know how can I improve my Dockerfile, I begin with rocketchat doc debian, then ubuntu, then snap (because its easier), and with all of them I got this error.

Comment: one more nail to the coffin of snapd

Answer (score 23, accepted):

first of all, you don't want to install the "snap" package, as it is not related to "snapd".
Secondly, myself stumbled across this issue of installing snapd within a docker container:
TLDR; Running snapd that way is currently not supported.

But that question has been asked already at the snapcraft forums.
One of snapd's dependencies is systemd and the snapd-service isn't properly initialized without a reboot or relogin. That is the required procedure according to the documentation across all distributions, but obviously isn't an option within docker.

At least this open question replicates your question most:
[unable-to-install-snapcraft-snap-in-docker-image-ubuntu-19-10](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/unable-to-install-snapcraft-snap-in-docker-image-ubuntu-19-10/13793)

And Evan [at the snapcraft forum here](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snapd-in-docker/177/13) posted an approach, that I couldn't get to work either.

The only approach that might work is similar to running docker inside of docker, i.e.:

- install snapd on the docker host
- mount the snapd-socket at runtime into the container that has snapd installed.

But same [warnings/side-effects](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/) apply as they do to running docker-in-docker.

Comment: That last link (about docker-in-docker) has a note saying it was updated in July 2020. I don't understand much of it. Can someone update this answer please? It looks like the original author has gone awol.

Comment: @DavidKnipe The note in the referenced page, is related to one of various approaches to get  docker-in-docker working. It can be neglected in this context. My answer proposes the bind mount of the snapd socket, which is just the same  as one the approaches there to get docker-in-docker working. And the warnings and side-effects still apply.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem too, but was able to use the EFF's [prebuilt Certbot images](https://hub.docker.com/r/certbot/certbot) on DockerHub

`FROM certbot/certbot:latest` (see [all tags](https://hub.docker.com/r/certbot/certbot/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated))

Comment: lifesaver ! I will add the commands I used in GCP's chrome-os

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on GCP's dedicated os for containers.
This is how it worked for me (based on the Joseph Lust's reply):

Before you start:

- Make sure the DNS is pointing to your VM external IP
- make sure that anyone can access port 80
- stop the container with your app if it is using port 80 (certbot container will create a http server on port 80)

Run the certbot container:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm --name certbot \
            -v "/etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt" \
            -v "/var/lib/letsencrypt:/var/lib/letsencrypt" \
            -p 80:80 \
            certbot/certbot certonly
```

Select option 1 and then input your domain. (Would be nice to find a way to automate this ... )

Start your container with mounted volumes for :

```
        -v "/etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt" 
        -v "/var/lib/letsencrypt:/var/lib/letsencrypt"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WSL2 you can overcome this problem by adding the following line in `/etc/wsl.conf`:

```ini
[boot]
systemd=true
```

Don't forget to restart WSL using PowerShell:

```
wsl.exe --shutdown
wsl.exe
```